# Is it possible with Eclipse to only find results in string literals?

Tags: eclipse, replace

Lets assume I have the following Java code:

```
public String foo()
{
  // returns foo()
  String log = "foo() : Logging something!"
  return log;
}
```

Can I search in Eclipse for `foo()` occurring only in a String literal, but not anywhere else in the code? So in the example here Eclipse should only find the third occurrance of `foo()`, not the first one, which is a function name and not the second one, which is a comment.

**Edit:** Simple Regular Expressions won't work, because they will find `foo()` in a line like

```
String temp = "literal" + foo() + "another literal"
```

But here `foo()` is a function name and not a String literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
"[^"\n]*foo\\(\\)[^"\n]*"
```

You have to escape brackets, plus this regex do not match new lines or additional quotes, which prevent wrong matches.

Comment: I think you meant `"[^"\n]*foo\\(\\)[^"\n]*"` . This is the best regex so far. But it will find a match in the line `String log = "bla" + foo() + "blabla"` where `foo()` is a function name. Also it will match String literals in comments like `// returns String "foo()"`.

Comment: @asmaier The regex could be improved, but then it may not be worth it. If you are planning to do an auto search-and-replace everywhere, forget it! Search and review every match manually. That's the only way to be sure the regex didn't matched some unexpected weird text.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use regex to find any occurence of foo() between two " ?

Comment: I'm no good with regex, so I'll just say it like this :
(0 or more ((one ")(0 or more (any character))(one ")))(one ")( 0 or more (any character but "))(foo())(0 or more (any character but "))(one ")